# How do I translate this block of embedded HTML into a Ruby helper method in the ApplicationHelper folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to DRY up my code, and I want to put this chunk of embedded HTML:

```
<ul>
  <% if flash[:errors] %>
    <% flash[:errors].each do | error | %>
      <li><%= error %></li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

into a helper method inside of my ApplicationHelper folder. I found a similar post about this that mentioned doing something like so:

```
def flash_errors
  if flash[:errors]
    flash[:errors].each do | error |
        error
    end
  end
end
```

However, when I try this out, I get an array of the error messages; I found it strange that it was returning an array at all (I assumed that the .each would go through and at least pull and print out each error message in the array):

```
["Email can't be blank", "Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"]
```

What is the correct syntax for translating this over into a helper method? I've also tried using html_safe on a string version of this html code, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: What does `flash[:errors].inspect` tell you? I'm guessing that you have a nested array `[["Email can't be blank", "Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"]]` and that you're actually just seeing the first element of the array. So you can either find out why you have a nested array or call `flash[:errors].flatten.each`.

Comment: @max: nope, no nested array here. This is just what `each` returns, the collection it iterated.

Comment: Can also just move it to a partial and render it as needed, or add to your layout and make it part of every page.

Comment: I moved it into a partial and it works like a charm! Thank you for the suggestion! Out of curiosity, if I have multiple lines of erb tags like my above example, is it better to put that into a partial than into a helper method?

Comment: It depends on the code. If its relatively simple logic then a partial does the job well and its often easier to read ERB than Ruby that produces HTML. If the logic is fairly complex then a helper will be more readable and easier to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write this as a helper you can do:

```
module FlashHelper
  def list_flashes(flashes)
    content_tag :ul, class: 'flash-list' do
      flashes.each do |msg|
        concat(content_tag( :li, msg, class: 'flash'))
      end
    end if flashes.any?
  end
end
```

Example use with a an array as a stand in for `flash[:errors]`:

```
<%= list_flashes(['a', 'b', 'c']) %>
```

Output:

```
<ul class="flash-list">
  <li class="flash">a</li>
  <li class="flash">b</li>
  <li class="flash">c</li>
</ul>
```

You could also write this as a partial and you should generally prefer writing HTML as ERB vs creating HTML strings in Ruby as the former is easier to read and properly indents.

Helpers are better though if you have complex logic as ERB becomes quite unreadable if there is too much going on.

For example you can create a helper method that takes the whole flash object and handles arrays and hashes:

```
module FlashHelper
  # @param [Array|Hash] flashes
  def list_flashes_recursive(flashes)
    return if flashes.empty?
    content_tag :ul, class: 'flash-list' do
      flashes.each do |key, msg|
        msg ||= key # lets us iterate through arrays as well
        case msg
        when Array, Hash
          concat(
            content_tag(:li, class: "flash-nested #{key}") do
              concat(list_flashes(msg))
            end
          )
        else
          concat(content_tag(:li, msg, class: "flash #{key}"))
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Example use with a hash as a stand in for `flash`:

```
<%= list_flashes_recursive(foo: 'bar', errors: ['a', 'b', 'c'], x: { y: 'z' }) %>
```

Output:

```
<ul class="flash-list">
  <li class="flash foo">bar</li>
  <li class="flash-nested errors">
    <ul class="flash-list">
      <li class="flash">a</li>
      <li class="flash">b</li>
      <li class="flash">c</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="flash-nested x">
    <ul class="flash-list">
      <li class="flash y">z</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this method in one of my project and it answers the exact question.

```
  def flash_messages(_opts = {})
    flash.delete(:timedout) # remove timeout set by Devise gem

    html = ''
    flash.each do |msg_type, message|
      html = <<~HTML
        <div class="alert alert--fixed alert-dismissible #{bootstrap_class_for(msg_type)}" role="alert")
          <i class="glyphicon #{bootstrap_icon_for(msg_type)}"></i>
          <button class="close" data-dismiss='alert'>
            <span aria-hidden="true"> &times;</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
          </button>
          <div class="alert__message">#{simple_format(message)}</div>
        </div>
      HTML
    end
    html.html_safe
  end
```

To be exact, it does more because the method also works for error, info and notice and uses the following methods and class variable for Bootstrap 3 theme.

```
  BOOTSTRAP_ALERT_TYPE = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(
    success: 'alert-success',
    error:   'alert-danger',
    alert:   'alert-warning',
    notice:  'alert-info'
  ).freeze

  BOOTSTRAP_ALERT_ICON = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(
    success: 'glyphicon-ok-circle',
    error:   'glyphicon-remove-circle',
    alert:   'glyphicon-warning-sign',
    notice:  'glyphicon-exclamation-sign'
  ).freeze

  # Rails 4 flash message using Twitter Bootstrap
  # https://gist.github.com/suryart/7418454
  def bootstrap_class_for(flash_type)
    BOOTSTRAP_ALERT_TYPE.fetch(flash_type.to_sym, 'alert-info')
    # flash_type.to_s
  end
```

Comment: How is this code directly relevant to the OP's question?

Comment: My bad. My code uses heredoc syntax and does not directly answer the question in all criteria.